# How to compute body padding based on navbar height?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

When an ASP.NET MVC application is created, it automatically generates a default navbar layout with a few menu items on the top left and a "Log in" menu item on the top right.

By default, the content of a page starts behind the navbar. As suggested by many posts, the culprit is the class `navbar-fixed-top` and one has to add `padding-top` for `body` style in your site-specific css file.

I chose a proper top padding size and it seemed to worked perfectly.

The problem happens when you start shortening the width of your browser on your desktop. At one point, the "Log in" menu item rolls over to the next line. The padding size I had specified is no longer valid.

I am wondering if there is a way to set the padding size dynamically based on navbar height. Or, perhaps there is a way to define two different padding sizes based on the current state of the navbar? Hopefully, I can apply the trick either in my site.css file or in my master layout file so that I don't need to modify each page. Regards.

Comment: the default MVC template comes with `padding-top: 50px` to the body. This works fine for me even when it falls within the `sm`(tablets) size.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code to solve the same problem, i'm not sure if i keep it, maybe it helps you.

```
(function ($) {

    var lastNavBarHeight = 100;

    checkSize(); // init
    $(window).resize(checkSize);

    // changes size of padding to the nav.navbar when responsive changes are fired
    function checkSize() {
        var navHeight = $("nav.navbar").height();

        if (navHeight !== lastNavBarHeight) {
            $("body").css("padding-top", navHeight + "px");
            lastNavBarHeight = navHeight;
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have figured out a cleaner way to take care of this problem using javascript. Will post my solution shortly. Regards.